# Discrepancy in address on passport and DS-160 form

Tags: visas, passports, paperwork, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm likely to get opportunity to go to US for Business purpose through our company. The process is likely to start from next week.

I'm Bachelor staying in Pune, India and I've following three addresses:

1. Present address is A (where I stay in Pune with friends)
2. Home address is B (where my parents stay(not in Pune district, it's in another district of Maharashtra, India). This is address I use as permanent address)
3. Address on passport is C (this is address of hostel in Pune where I used to stay when I was student and had got passport while I was in college).

Still address on passport is C, because I didn't change address since my Present address and Home address keep changing. Present address keep changing because I'm bachelor, keep changing flat and Home address keep changing because my father is government servant in Postal services and his job location is also keep changing.

While filling up DS-160 form if I've following:

1. Mailing address = A
2. Home address = B

   But my address on passport = C which is different than above two.

Will this likely to result in Visa cancellation?

And, I've less time to update passport address since I've to start Visa process from next week immediately. Please suggest if above situation works or another solution for this that will help in such a short period.

Comment: Are you saying the DS-160 actually has a field for the address on your passport?  It's been a year or so since I last filled in a DS-160, but I don't recall such a field.  (Plus, most countries passports don't actually have an address on them)

Comment: Thanks Doc, for replying! In DS-160 form, there is no field for 'address on your passport'. There are only two fields - home address and mailing address. In my case, all these three addresses are different.(Indian passports do have address on it)

Comment: Sample Indian passport - http://www.immihelp.com/nri/indianpassport/sample-indian-passport.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Don't worry about it**.  Most countries' passports do not have addresses at all, so the passport address is not a part of your application.

Also, the officers processing your application will understand that the address printed on the passport is the address you had when you received the passport, not necessarily your current address, especially since in India [the only way to change the passport address](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqServicesAvailable) is to get an entirely new passport issued.

Comment: Thank you so much jpatokal! It really doesn't matter.

Comment: @TDHM could you post an answer or comment confirming the outcome?  Thanks!

Comment: @phoog, address did not matter and I could go through it without any issue