# Misspelt address on passport

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, embassies

I am an Indian citizen in the USA (Houghton, Michigan). I am on an F1 visa right now and had reapplied for a "renewal of passport". All the correct forms were submitted to the Indian Consulate of my jurisdiction (Chicago).

I received my new passport **but** the name of the town in which I reside has been *misspelt* as HOUGHRON and NOT HOUGHTON. The consulate put an "r" in the town's name where they should have had a "t".

Now is this going to be an issue for future travel? The embassy is unresponsive in this matter and I need to travel abroad (apply for a visa) soon.

I realize that to get anything changed on the ["laminated pages of a passport"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/23207/2236) I would need to "reapply" for a passport. Is it really my best course of action or is the "current address" inconsequential that has been misspelt.

If I do plan on reapplying for a passport again, none of the forms that I fill out have any field or space to mention that this is as a result of a "change in address" type situation.

Is this my best course of action? What is [suggested is this](http://passport.blsindia-usa.com/changeaddress.php#tabs-quote-Chicago).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The address is mostly a convenience (in case the passport gets lost). In my country, reporting an address change is not mandatory and Canada [even advises you to change it yourself](http://www.ppt.gc.ca/support/faq.aspx?lang=eng&id=q4003). It might be a problem as far as the Indian authorities are concerned so I wouldn't recommend doing that but there is no way a third country could verify it or rely on it for any official purposes so traveling won't be an issue. Beside your own country and your country of residence, I don't think anybody cares about your address anyway.

When applying for a visa, you do however need to make sure that the relevant consulate has your current address (but applicants are often required to provide a pre-paid envelop anyway). For a simple misspelling, if the zip code is correct, I am not even sure sending something to that address would be a problem in practice.

Comment: After several phone calls across the atlantic with several Indian passport offices, I have learned that the address is not a very important aspect of a passport. The passport first page with name, age etc. are far more important. Although the consulate general of India suggested that I could have the "change" noted on my passport's observation page, a little research revealed that this would not be a good idea. Read [this](www.vfs-germany.co.in/Bangalore/allaboutvisa.html)